# screenshot in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Hello I'm creating a screen snipping application and I'm displaying an image to a label. Below is a brief code block of how I'm saving and displaying this image.

```
self.snippedImg = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=r.getCoords()) # got what I needed
self.snippedImg.save("snips/testImage.png") # Don't want to have to save it to use this image

self.screenshotLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('snips/testImage.png')
self.screenshotLabel.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
self.setCentralWidget(self.screenshotLabel)
self.screenshotLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

Ideally the code would look something like... where x would be the stored non-file image.

```
x = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=r.getCoords())
self.screenshotLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(x)
self.screenshotLabel.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
self.setCentralWidget(self.screenshotLabel)
self.screenshotLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

If I can use PYQT5 solely (without PIL) that is even better. I will respond fast to follow up questions. Thank you.

Comment: use `screen = QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen() window = windowHandle() if window: screen = window.screen() pixmap = screen.grabWindow(0)`

Comment: `pixmap = pixmap.copy(r)`